# Shell Error: Jenkins not reading sub command

Tags: linux, shell, svn, jenkins, merge

For some reason, jenkins is having issues running this section of code:

```
svn merge --reintegrate ../branches/${BRANCH_TO_MERGE} --username "${LDAP_USER_ID}" --password "${LDAP_USER_PASSWD}" >$logfile 2>&1
```

However when written as below...it works!!!?

cd ${WORKSPACE}/workspace/trunk

```
svn merge ../branches/${BRANCH_TO_MERGE} --username "${LDAP_USER_ID}" --password "${LDAP_USER_PASSWD}" >$logfile 2>&1
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the first command throwing some error? Also, which version of SVN are you using?

Comment: Yes, you forgot to tell us what the error message is or what exactly makes you believe Jenkins is having issues with your code.